# php preg_match for faceted search string

Tags: php, preg-match

I'm looking to php preg_match to break out a faceted search string.

example search input:
chevy tahoe city:seattle color:desert dune capacity:7

- search criteria:  chevy tahoe
- city facet: seattle
- color facet: desert dune
- capacity facet: 7

search criteria will always be first in the input string...but the facets could be interchangeable.

Comment: What have you tried? What output were you expecting? What output did you get?

Comment: Trying to make the input more "parsable" by changing its format slightly would be a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. It should work.

```
$criteria = '';
$facets = array();
foreach (explode(' ' , $input) as $word) {

    // This word is a facet
    if (strpos($word, ':')) {
        list($facet_name, $facet_criteria) = explode(':', $word, 1);
        $facets[$facet_name] = $facet_criteria;

    // This word is a search criteria
    } else {
        $criteria .= $word . ' ';
    }

}
```

Input (`$input` value):

```
chevy tahoe city:seattle color:desert dune capacity:7
```

Output:

```
$criteria: chevy tahoe dune 

$facets: Array (
    [city] => seattle
    [color] => desert
    [capacity] => 7
)
```

Comment: This describes a different way to look at the possible solution.  I will need to tweak your answer just a bit to allow for multiple word facets...but nonetheless, your answer has definitely helped.  Thanks